# Creating a directory to store source files and class files separately. However, I'm not able to extend one class to another in the same package

Tags: java, package

Following is the directory flow which i'm trying to create:

**company** folder.

under company folder I have **class** folder and **source** folder.

under source folder I have pack1 folder.

->**company\class**

->**company\source\pack1**

Inside pack1 folder I have save two source files : A.java and B.java where class B extends class A.

->**company\source\pack1\A.java**

->**company\source\pack1\B.java**

Now I want to compile class A and class B and store the class files of A and B under **Company\class\pack1**

The class files should be stored this way:

->**company\class\pack1\A.class**

->**company\class\pack1\B.class**

## General code:

```
package pack1;
public class A
{
  //class A implementation
}

----------------------------------------
package pack1;
public class B extends A
{
  //class B implementation
}
```

The command i used in command prompt is

```
F:\company\source\pack1> javac -d ../../class A.java
```

There was no problem. **A.class** was created inside **company\class\pack1**

But, i tried compiling B.java

```
F:\company\source\pack1> javac -d ../../class B.java
```

i got the following error:

```
B.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
public class B extends A
                   ^
symbol: class A
1 error
```

I searched everywhere. I am unable to sleep because of this. I am a beginner for java and I want to know why I am not able to inherit form class A to class B even though both the source files are inside the same folder.

Please brief me in detail. Thanks

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193554/pies-den  @Pyro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiling class B requires that the compiler knows the class A. It is not part of the sources that the compiler is working on and it is not on the classpath. So the 2 solutions I see are:

a) compile the sources together e.g.

```
javac -d ../../class A.java B.java
```

b) Make sure that class A can be found on the classpath when compiling B:

```
javac -d ../../class A.java
javac -d ../../class -cp ../../class B.java
```